# You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests in jest for a class in my node project. I've already read other threads of people having this error but I can't solve this by following their instructions.
So, whenever I use the command "npm run test" I get this message:

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From __tests__/calendar/calendarEvents.test.ts.
```

This is the code for my test:

```
import { PreorderController } from '../../src/classes/libraryofthings/PreorderController';
import { MongoServer } from './db/MongoServer';
import { afterAll, beforeAll, describe, expect, jest, test } from '@jest/globals';

describe('jest testing', () => {
    let mongoServer;
    beforeAll(async () => {
        mongoServer = new MongoServer();
        await mongoServer.start();
    })
    afterAll(async () => {
        await mongoServer.stop();
    })
    test('it saves a new preorder using the preorder controller class', () => {
        const controller = new PreorderController();
    })
})
```

I'm not doing anything fancy because I'm trying to debug this error here. So that's why you don't see any expect in the test case.
This is the code of the class:

```
import { PreorderCreated } from "../../models/events/LibOfThings/Preorders";
import Preorder, { PreorderCreated as PreorderCreatedMongo } from "../../models/mongodb/Calendar/Preorder";
import { AvailableEvents, PossibleStatuses } from "../../types/calendar";
import { Web3Controller } from "../web3/Web3Controller";
import { PreroderInDB } from "./Preorder";

export class PreorderController {
    private web3Controller: Web3Controller;
    private timeout: number;
    private possibleStatuses: PossibleStatuses = {
        pending: 'Pending',
        cancelled: 'Cancelled',
        denied: 'Denied',
        accepted: 'Accepted',
        ended: 'Ended',
        started: 'Started'
    }
    private availableEvents: AvailableEvents = {
        preorderCreated: 'PreorderCreated',
        preorderAccepted: 'PreorderAccepted',
        preorderCancelled: 'PreorderCancelled',
        preorderDenied: 'PreorderDenied',
        preorderStarted: 'PreorderStarted',
        preorderEnded: 'PreorderEnded',
    }

    constructor() {
        this.timeout = 1000;
        this.web3Controller = new Web3Controller();
    }

    async getPreorder(id: string): Promise<PreorderCreatedMongo> {
        return await Preorder.findOne({ preorderID: id });
    }

    async savePreorderInMongo(preorderCreatedObj: PreorderCreated, timestamp: number, userInfo: {
        lenderAddressInfo: string,
        borrowerAddressInfo: string
    }, address: string, realm: string): Promise<void> {
        try {
            console.log(`Handle preorder created: ${new Date()}`);
            const preorder = await Preorder.findOne({ preorderID: preorderCreatedObj._preorderID });
            if (preorder == null) {
                console.log(`New preorder data = ${JSON.stringify(preorderCreatedObj)} with ID: ${preorderCreatedObj._preorderID}`);
                console.log(`Preorder is null, adding its document in the colleciton "Preorder"`)
                await Preorder.create({
                    "preorderID": preorderCreatedObj._preorderID,
                    "itemID": preorderCreatedObj._idItem,
                    "startDate": preorderCreatedObj._startDate,
                    "endDate": preorderCreatedObj._endDate,
                    "timestamp": timestamp,
                    "lender": preorderCreatedObj._lender,
                    "status": this.possibleStatuses.pending,
                    "borrower": preorderCreatedObj._borrower,
                    "contractAddress": address,
                    "realm": realm,
                    "lenderFSName": userInfo.lenderAddressInfo,
                    "borrowerFSName": userInfo.borrowerAddressInfo,
                    "itemName": preorderCreatedObj._itemName
                })
            } else {
                console.log(`Preorder with ID = ${preorderCreatedObj._preorderID} already exists in 'preorders' collection`);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    async updateStatus(id: string, newStatus: string, blockNumber: number): Promise<void>
    async updateStatus(id: string, newStatus: string, blockNumber: number, comment: string): Promise<void>
    async updateStatus(id: string, newStatus: string, blockNumber: number, comment: string, itemWasFine: boolean): Promise<void>
    async updateStatus(id: string, newStatus: string, blockNumber: number, comment?: string, itemWasFine?: boolean): Promise<void> {
        const timestamp = await this.web3Controller.getBlockTimestamp(blockNumber);

        const preorder = await this.getPreorder(id);
        if (!preorder) {
            await sleep(this.timeout);
            return this.updateStatus(id, newStatus, blockNumber, comment, itemWasFine);
        } else {
            if ((timestamp as Number) > preorder.timestamp) {
                const preorderInstance = new PreroderInDB(newStatus, id);
                await preorderInstance.updateStatus(newStatus, timestamp);
                if (newStatus === this.possibleStatuses.ended)
                    await preorderInstance.addReviewInfoToPreorder(comment, itemWasFine);
            }
        }
    }

    getPreorderStatusAssociatedWithEvent(eventType: string): string {
        let status: string;

        switch (eventType) {
            case this.availableEvents.preorderCreated:
                status = this.possibleStatuses.pending;
                break;
            case this.availableEvents.preorderAccepted:
                status = this.possibleStatuses.accepted;
                break;
            case this.availableEvents.preorderCancelled:
                status = this.possibleStatuses.cancelled;
                break;
            case this.availableEvents.preorderDenied:
                status = this.possibleStatuses.denied;
                break;
            case this.availableEvents.preorderStarted:
                status = this.possibleStatuses.started;
                break;
            case this.availableEvents.preorderEnded:
                status = this.possibleStatuses.ended;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error(`I don\'t know what to do with this event type: ${eventType}`);
        }

        return status;
    }


    getPreorderAvailableStautuses(): PossibleStatuses {
        return this.possibleStatuses;
    }

    getAvailableEvents(): AvailableEvents {
        return this.availableEvents;
    }

    eventPreorderCreatedReceived(eventName: string): boolean {
        return eventName === this.availableEvents.preorderCreated;
    }

    eventPreorderEndedReceived(eventName: string): boolean {
        return eventName === this.availableEvents.preorderEnded;
    }
}


const sleep = (ms: number) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

I think it has something to do with the setTimeout function I have in my custom sleep() function, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the below statement after your `import` statements (but before the `describe`) in your test file: `__tests__/calendar/calendarEvents.test.ts`

```
jest.useFakeTimers()
```

This is used by jest to mock `setTimeout` which you are using in `PreorderController`.

> The native timer functions (i.e., setTimeout(), setInterval(), clearTimeout(), clearInterval()) are less than ideal for a testing environment since they depend on real time to elapse. Jest can swap out timers with functions that allow you to control the passage of time.
>
> https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks